# Invalid module format

Tags: makefile, linux-kernel, kernel-module

```
$insmod helloworld module generates the error message "Invalid module format".

$dmesg outputs:

overflow in relocation type 10 val ffffffff88640070
'hello' likely not compiled with -mcmodel=kernel
```

The Makefile is a mix of tradition format (using (CC)) and module build system format `"make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules"`.

The system is 1.6.18-194.el5 x86_64. The same Makefile works fine when it is used in i386 machine.

Any idea of what to look into? Thanks.

---

```
#Makefile, mix of (CC) and kernel module build system

CFLAGS+=-D"KBUILD_STR(s)=\#s" -D"KBUILD_BASENAME=KBUILD_STR(hello)"
CFLAGS+=-D__KERNEL__ -DMODULE -I$(KERNEL_BUILD_DIR)/include

KERNEL_BUILD_DIR=/lib/modules/2.6.18-194.el5/build
TARGETNAME=hello
BUILD_ALT_DIR=linux

# The main target (note that both library and driver are .ko files
#
all: $(BUILD_ALT_DIR)/$(TARGETNAME).ko
$(BUILD_ALT_DIR)/_$(TARGETNAME).o: hello.o
@echo Linking objects to loadable module
@mkdir -p $(BUILD_ALT_DIR)
@echo $(CURDIR)/$@
@$(LD) -Map=$@.map -r -o $@ $^
@echo " LD_D [$@]"

$(BUILD_ALT_DIR)/$(TARGETNAME).ko: $(BUILD_ALT_DIR)/_$(TARGETNAME).o
@rm -f $(BUILD_ALT_DIR)/$(TARGETNAME).o
@echo create Makefile
@$(SHELL) -c 'echo "obj-m := $(TARGETNAME).o" > $(BUILD_ALT_DIR)/Makefile'
@$(SHELL) -c 'echo "$(TARGETNAME)-objs := _$(TARGETNAME).o" >> $(BUILD_ALT_DIR)/Makefile'
@$(SHELL) -c 'echo ".PHONY: `pwd`/$(BUILD_ALT_DIR)/_$(TARGETNAME).o" >> $(BUILD_ALT_DIR)/Makefile'
@$(SHELL) -c 'cd $(BUILD_ALT_DIR); $(MAKE) -C $(KERNEL_BUILD_DIR) M=`pwd`'
@echo " KO_D [$@]"


$(BUILD_ALT_DIR)/%.o: %.c
@echo Compiling C source to object file:
@mkdir -p $(BUILD_ALT_DIR)
# @echo $(CURDIR)/$@
@$(CC) -c -Wall $(CFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
@echo " CC_D [$@]"

clean:
    rm -f $(BUILD_ALT_DIR)/*.o $(BUILD_ALT_DIR)/*.d  $(BUILD_ALT_DIR)/core  $(BUILD_ALT_DIR)/*.map
```

### hello.c

```
#include <linux/autoconf.h> // this is needed

#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h> 

static int hello_init(void)
{ 
  printk(KERN_ALERT "Hello, world\n");

    return 0;
}

static void hello_exit(void)
{
    printk(KERN_ALERT "Goodbye, cruel world\n");
}

module_init(hello_init);
module_exit(hello_exit);
```

Comment: What to look into? Apart from *Elements of Style*? Well, you could show us the makefile rule(s) in question.

Comment: Thanks for reply, the Makefile is a little bit long, i added excerpt of it in the Question.

Comment: This make take a few iterations. I take it that you are trying to build "helloworld"; can you confirm that you can make `build_alt_dir/_helloworld.o` (or whatever)? Then the `.ko` tries to build a makefile using what appears to be an unnecessary `SHELL` indirection. Does it succeed? Then it tries to to execute that makefile with... *quintuple* indirection!? Well, one step at a time.

Comment: Yes, _helloworld.o is generated. SHELL commands are used to create a Makefile that runs module build system "$(MAKE) -C $(KERNEL_BUILD_DIR) M=`pwd`". This Makefile works on i386, so I am wondering if there is a new requirement/configuration for x86_64?

Answer (score 4):

The `dmesg` output tells you what is wrong:

```
'hello' likely not compiled with -mcmodel=kernel
```

On the x86-64 architecture, all code running in the kernel (including modules) *must* be compiled with a special flag, which tells the compiler to generate code which will run in the top half of the virtual address space (user mode programs run on the bottom half of the address space).

If I am reading your Makefile correctly, you are compiling the C code *outside* the kernel build system, and calling into the kernel build system only for the final linking. **Do not do this.** It is not just the memory model, there are several other flags which must be added when compiling the C source code. These flags can change with the kernel version, or even with the kernel configuration — you do not know, and you are not supposed to have to know, since the kernel build system deals with it all for you.

It is not just `-mcmodel=kernel`. There are many others, and getting them wrong can and will cause problems.

The fact that you are missing the correct flags is quite visible in your code:

```
#include <linux/autoconf.h> // this is needed
```

No, this is not needed. If you need it, you are doing it wrong. Take a look at one of the flags the kernel build system passes to the C compiler:

```
-include include/linux/autoconf.h
```

This flags tells the C compiler to always implicitly include the `linux/autoconf.h` header. Since it is always implicitly included, you never have to include it manually. And since you never include it manually, its location is allowed to change — it moved to `generated/autoconf.h` and later to `linux/kconfig.h`, and who knows where else it will end up next.

The fact that it worked at all for you in 32-bit x86 is just luck. You should do it the correct way even on 32-bit.

Comment: Your answer is greatly appreciated, it provides valuable information. Just FYI, I have to include "#include <linux/autoconf.h>" in source code in order to make it compile, otherwise, lots of compilation errors, now I know why. Could you explain what "its location is allowed to change" means?

Comment: @YHH: since it should never be included directly, the kernel developers can (and do) change its location on new releases without worrying about whether they are breaking third-party code.

Answer (score 0):

Second iteration:

All right, you've confirmed that Make builds `_helloworld.o` and `$(BUILD_ALT_DIR)/Makefile`. Now could you post the makefile that's in `$(KERNEL_BUILD_DIR)` (on the x86_64)?

(I'll go out on a limb and suggest that maybe `$(BUILD_ALT_DIR)` and `$(KERNEL_BUILD_DIR)` are the same on the i386 but not on the x84_64.)

**EDIT:** (third iteration)
1400 lines? Most of that in *one branch?* Half a dozen `include` directives? Architecture-specific branches? Autoconf?

Are you allowed to modify this nightmare in place, or must you tinker with the higher-level tools like automake? (I ask only because in the latter case it won't do much good to figure out what the problem is, you'll probably have to start over from scratch.)

1) From $(KERNEL_BUILD_DIR), try `make M=$(BUILD_ALT_DIR)` (whatever `$(BUILD_ALT_DIR)` is). Verify that that gives you the same error message. If it doesn't then ignore what follows (in this iteration).

2) From `$(BUILD_ALT_DIR)`, try `make`, and see if it gives the same error. If it does, try replacing the makefile (in `$(BUILD_ALT_DIR)`) with a trivial makefile like

```
all:
    @echo trivial makefile working
```

and test it, then try step 1 again. **If it just says "trivial makefile working" and doesn't give the error, then things look good.**

**EDIT:** (fourth iteration)

All right, we can't change `$(KERNEL_BUILD_DIR)/Makefile`. That doesn't necessarily sink us.

*"Your suggestion (1) would not work, since $(BUILD_ALT_DIR) is a output directory, no source is in it."*

Make does not require the presence of source code, and whether or not this would work (whatever "work" means), it is what your makefile appears to be attempting:

```
@$(SHELL) -c 'cd $(BUILD_ALT_DIR); $(MAKE) -C $(KERNEL_BUILD_DIR) M=`pwd`'
```

Try it and see what happens.

*"Is there a possibility that x86_64 doesn't support tradition format (CC) for the kernel module?"*

I'm not entirely sure what you mean, but we can probably answer your question by experiment.

Comment: Thanks you so much for helping me. $(BUILD_ALT_DIR) is just our directory for outputs, it is not a system directory. The Makefile in /usr/src/kernels/2.6.18-194.el5-x86_64 is very long, i put it at http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/insmod-failed-with-invalid-module-format-1-a-887801/. There are two posts for that.

Comment: The Makefile at /usr/src/kernels/2.6.18-194.el5-x86_64 is system's Makefile, it is not our Makefile, the module build system always calls this Makefile from command "$(MAKE) -C $(KERNEL_BUILD_DIR) M=pwd".

Comment: Your suggestion (1) would not work, since $(BUILD_ALT_DIR) is a output directory, no source is in it. If the entire package of the helloworld would help, you may send email to yuhua2050@yahoo.com, then i will send the package to you. Thanks.

Comment: is there a possibility that x86_64 doesn't support tradition format (CC) for the kernel module?

Comment: What i meant is if we have to strictly follow kernel module build system in x86_64, no regular Makefile format is allowed. I updated the Question, now the Makefile and hello.c is there, you can build hello module using Makefile and test it. Thanks.

Comment: You may see some differences comparing with module build system format, such as those defines with -D in Makefile, #include <linux/autoconf.h> in hello.c, those are needed for the module to build.