# C++ support in kernel module in 64-bit system

Tags: c++, linux, kernel-module

I know C++ is not recommended in kernel module, however, we have a module written in a mix of C and C++ files, the module works well in 32-bit system (kernel 2.6), now we are trying to port the module to 64-bit system, is C++ not supported at all in 64-bit system?

Comment: Did it work when you tried it?

Comment: neither is it supported in 32-bit.   if it works, it is pure luck.

Comment: read this: http://www.tux.org/lkml/#s15-3

Comment: I wonder what would happen to those Linux folks if you pointed out to them that their beloved gcc compiler is in fact the same as the evil g++ compiler.

Comment: @MSalters: they would probably tell you that it isn't. Which is true.

Comment: @Martinho Fernandes: I have some issues believing people who tell me that it takes 30 weeks to check the kernel for use of C++ keywords as C symbols (see 0A0D's link). I'd fire an intern who takes more than 30 _hours_.

Comment: @MSalters: I don't disagree with that. I think there are already tools for that: compiler + grep. But `gcc` is not the same as `g++`. They're two compilers that are part of the GNU Compiler Collection, also known as GCC.

Comment: The tux reference says that they tried C++ once in 1992 - it didn't work. So, there!

Comment: The module doesn't load in 64-bit system. I heard that a C++ compatibility layer is available for 32-bit environment, but doesn't exist for 64-bit environment, do you know anything about this?

Comment: @Martinho Fernandes: ["When referring to C++ compilation, it is usual to call the compiler “G++”. Since there is **only one** compiler, it is also accurate to call it “GCC”"](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.3.6/gcc/G_002b_002b-and-GCC.html)

Answer (score 3):

Roughly speaking, to use C++ in kernel, you should get rid of all C++ runtime library dependencies, first of all, you should reimplement `new/delete` and remove exception handling (compile with `-fno-exceptions`). Actually if the 32-bit code works, those simple cases must be already resolved.

Just try to compile and load the module. If you are lucky, there will be no linkage errors, and you have a good chance for a module to work (modulo the usual set of crossplatform issues such as structure sizes and alignment). If you are not, you will receive a list of undefined symbols that will give you a hint what should be implemented or worked around.

Comment: Thanks, we use a Makefile that is not a standard kernel Makefile, module builds but fails loading, so i simplify the module with "hello world", see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6471359/invalid-module-format. It looks that 64-bit system doesn't like this Makefile, although it works with 32-bit system, so i tried standard kernel Makefile, because the module is mixed with C and C++, system links the objects to c libraries, so i got linking WARNINGs which make the module fail to load, do you know a way (Makefile) to build a module mixed with c and c++?

Answer (score 2):

It's not a question of whether the *language* is supported on 64-bit, but whether the libraries and other code are portable.